# What is the GUI engine used to create Visual Studio itself?

Tags: visual-studio

It really bugs me not knowing what is the GUI engine used to create Microsoft Visual Studio ? is it Winforms (which i doubt) or WPF or what ? also most recent apps like FL Studio which offers a pretty fluid user interface with without any glitches or FPS drops what engine did they use to provide us with such smooth experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mix of WinForms, WPF, and legacy C++.

In newer versions, more of the UI was ported to WPF.

For more details, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/#visual-studio) or your favorite decompiler.

Comment: if you know FL Studio (the music production application) which has amazingly detailed/fluid UI what engine is capable of doing such smooth transitions and ui at all ?

Comment: @DanielEugen Reply a bit too late I guess, but FL Studio uses Delphi and all its UI is custom drawn